# Loop an array of objects and calculate the total marks

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

an array containing the value of student name and subject with key and marks

```js
let students = [
    {
        name: "Sham",
        sub: {
            math: 95,
            eng: 90,
            science: 99
        }
    },
    {
        name: "Peter",
        sub:{
            math: 80,
            eng: 70,
            science: 60
        }
    },
    {
        name: "Bob",
        sub:{
            math:70,
            eng:75,
            science:95
        }
    }
]
```

I want to calculate the total marks of each student and store them in an object and console it with the name and the total mark of each student

Comment: Sounds good. Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Or wait and get lucky. I'm sure this has been asked a hundred times...

Comment: Check my answer as simple as working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of simply providing the answer I think it is better to guide with the approach:

1. You know that in your final result you need one item per student. Since, you have an array of student objects, you need to use .map() or other for loop constructs.
2. You need to do a calculation on the subject key of each student object. You can do that inside your for loop/[.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) based on what you chose in step 1.
3. Now sub is not an array but an object. And you want to do an action on all values of that object. You can access them using [Object.values(sub)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values). This will return an array.
4. To perform a calculation on an array of objects which returns a single result, the ideal approach would be to choose [.reduce()](https://www.google.com/search?q=reduce+mdn&oq=reduce+mdn&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30l2j0i10i22i30j0i22i30.4625j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Since this a simple sum calculation, you can find numerous examples on the internet, and directly in the MDN docs too.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all students and then sum the values. Push the newly created object (for each student) back into the previously defined array `result`

```js
let result = [];
let students = [{name: "Sham",sub: {math: 95,eng: 90,science: 99}},{name: "Peter",sub:{math: 80,eng: 70,science: 60}},{name: "Bob",sub:{math:70,eng:75,science:95}}];

students.forEach( student => {
  result.push({
    name: student.name,
    marks: Object.values(student.sub).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
  })
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Just answering with code does not help the OP and future readers searching for similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below by using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
const result = students.reduce((acc, student) => {
        if (acc[student.name]) {
                return {
                        ...acc,
                        [student.name]: {
                                ...acc[student.name],
                                total: student.sub.math + student.sub.eng + student.sub.science + acc[student.name].total,
                                marks: Object.values(student.sub).reduce((acc, mark) => acc + mark, 0) + acc[student.name].total
                        }
                }
        } else {
                return {
                        ...acc,
                        [student.name]: {
                                name: student.name,
                                total: student.sub.math + student.sub.eng + student.sub.science, // kept for understanding.
                                marks: Object.values(student.sub).reduce((acc, mark) => acc + mark, 0) // more better way doing it.
                        }
                }
        }
}, {});

console.log('result', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript native functions for calculatation.

```
 let students = [
    {
        name: "Sham",
        sub: {
            math: 95,
            eng: 90,
            science: 99
        }
    },
    {
        name: "Peter",
        sub:{
            math: 80,
            eng: 70,
            science: 60
        }
    },
    {
        name: "Bob",
        sub:{
            math:70,
            eng:75,
            science:95
        }
    }
];

let result = [];


students.forEach( student => {
  result.push({
    name: student.name,
    marks: Object.values(student.sub).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
    });
});
```

Result :

```
[ { name: 'Sham', marks: 284 },
  { name: 'Peter', marks: 210 },
  { name: 'Bob', marks: 240 } ]
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a little modification to the previous response by caramba

```
let result = [];
let students = [{ name: "Sham", sub: { math: 95, eng: 90, science: 99 } }, { name: "Peter", sub: { math: 80, eng: 70, science: 60 } }, { name: "Bob", sub: { math: 70, eng: 75, science: 95 } }];

students.forEach(student => {
    result.push({
        name: student.name,
        marks: Object.values(student.sub).reduce((a, b, c) => (a + b + c)/3)
    })
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: what is the reason you divide it by 2

Comment: To get the average

Comment: the usage of .reduce() is incorrect, Your code returns the sum of third of the marks plus its indices plus the accumulator divided by three at each iteration